# AttributeError: module 'm5' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, gem5

I'm going through the gem5 tutorial and trying to run gem5 with the following script in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py
```

This is a link to the tutorial:
https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/simple_config/

 This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'm5' has no attribute 'main'
```

I already checked The Mail Archive for gem5 and it says the problem could be with the M5 package which could be installed in Python3. 
https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=gem5-users@gem5.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5Bgem5%5C-users%5C%5D+Re%5C%3A+AttributeError%5C%3A+module+%27m5%27+has+no+attribute+%27main%27%22&o=newest&f=1

But I checked and M5 is not installed in Python3 and m5 is.

```
 >>> import M5
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'M5'
 >>> import m5
 >>> print(m5.__dict__)
 {'__name__': 'm5', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'm5', 
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object 
 at 0x7f6f7a0637c0>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='m5', loader= 
 <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 
 0x7f6f7a0637c0>, origin='/home/mobin/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/m5/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations= 
 ['/home/mobin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/m5']), 
 '__path__': ['/home/mobin/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/m5'], '__file__': 
 '/home/mobin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/m5/__init__.py', 
 '__cached__': '/home/mobin/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/m5/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc', '__builtins__': 
 {'__name__': 'builtins', '__doc__': "Built-in functions, 
 exceptions, and other objects.\n\nNoteworthy: None is the `nil' 
 object; Ellipsis represents `...' in slices.", '__package__': '', 
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 
 '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class 
 '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>), '__build_class__': <built- 
 in function __build_class__>, '__import__': <built-in function 
 __import__>, 'abs': <built-in function abs>, 'all': <built-in 
 function all>, 'any': <built-in function any>, 'ascii': <built-in 
 function ascii>, 'bin': <built-in function bin>, 'breakpoint': 
 <built-in function breakpoint>, 'callable': <built-in function 
 callable>, 'chr': <built-in function chr>, 'compile': <built-in 
 function compile>, 'delattr': <built-in function delattr>, 'dir': 
 <built-in function dir>, 'divmod': <built-in function divmod>, 
 'eval': <built-in function eval>, 'exec': <built-in function 
 exec>, 'format': <built-in function format>, 'getattr': <built-in 
 function getattr>, 'globals': <built-in function globals>, 
 'hasattr': <built-in function hasattr>, 'hash': <built-in 
 function hash>, 'hex': <built-in function hex>, 'id': <built-in 
 function id>, 'input': <built-in function input>, 'isinstance': 
 <built-in function isinstance>, 'issubclass': <built-in function 
 issubclass>, 'iter': <built-in function iter>, 'len': <built-in 
 function len>, 'locals': <built-in function locals>, 'max': 
 <built-in function max>, 'min': <built-in function min>, 'next': 
 <built-in function next>, 'oct': <built-in function oct>, 'ord': 
 <built-in function ord>, 'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'print': 
 <built-in function print>, 'repr': <built-in function repr>, 
 'round': <built-in function round>, 'setattr': <built-in function 
 setattr>, 'sorted': <built-in function sorted>, 'sum': <built-in 
 function sum>, 'vars': <built-in function vars>, 'None': None, 
 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'NotImplemented': NotImplemented, 'False': 
 False, 'True': True, 'bool': <class 'bool'>, 'memoryview': <class 
 'memoryview'>, 'bytearray': <class 'bytearray'>, 'bytes': <class 
 'bytes'>, 'classmethod': <class 'classmethod'>, 'complex': <class 
 'complex'>, 'dict': <class 'dict'>, 'enumerate': <class 
 'enumerate'>, 'filter': <class 'filter'>, 'float': <class 
 'float'>, 'frozenset': <class 'frozenset'>, 'property': <class 
 'property'>, 'int': <class 'int'>, 'list': <class 'list'>, 'map': 
 <class 'map'>, 'object': <class 'object'>, 'range': <class 
 'range'>, 'reversed': <class 'reversed'>, 'set': <class 'set'>, 
 'slice': <class 'slice'>, 'staticmethod': <class 'staticmethod'>, 
 'str': <class 'str'>, 'super': <class 'super'>, 'tuple': <class 
 'tuple'>, 'type': <class 'type'>, 'zip': <class 'zip'>, 
 '__debug__': True, 'BaseException': <class 'BaseException'>, 
 'Exception': <class 'Exception'>, 'TypeError': <class 
 'TypeError'>, 'StopAsyncIteration': <class 'StopAsyncIteration'>, 
 'StopIteration': <class 'StopIteration'>, 'GeneratorExit': <class 
 'GeneratorExit'>, 'SystemExit': <class 'SystemExit'>, 
 'KeyboardInterrupt': <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>, 'ImportError': 
 <class 'ImportError'>, 'ModuleNotFoundError': <class 
 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, 'OSError': <class 'OSError'>, 
 'EnvironmentError': <class 'OSError'>, 'IOError': <class 
 'OSError'>, 'EOFError': <class 'EOFError'>, 'RuntimeError': 
 <class 'RuntimeError'>, 'RecursionError': <class 
 'RecursionError'>, 'NotImplementedError': <class 
 'NotImplementedError'>, 'NameError': <class 'NameError'>, 
 'UnboundLocalError': <class 'UnboundLocalError'>, 
 'AttributeError': <class 'AttributeError'>, 'SyntaxError': <class 
 'SyntaxError'>, 'IndentationError': <class 'IndentationError'>, 
 'TabError': <class 'TabError'>, 'LookupError': <class 
 'LookupError'>, 'IndexError': <class 'IndexError'>, 'KeyError': 
 <class 'KeyError'>, 'ValueError': <class 'ValueError'>, 
 'UnicodeError': <class 'UnicodeError'>, 'UnicodeEncodeError': 
 <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>, 'UnicodeDecodeError': <class 
 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, 'UnicodeTranslateError': <class 
 'UnicodeTranslateError'>, 'AssertionError': <class 
 'AssertionError'>, 'ArithmeticError': <class 'ArithmeticError'>, 
 'FloatingPointError': <class 'FloatingPointError'>, 
 'OverflowError': <class 'OverflowError'>, 'ZeroDivisionError': 
 <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, 'SystemError': <class 
 'SystemError'>, 'ReferenceError': <class 'ReferenceError'>, 
 'MemoryError': <class 'MemoryError'>, 'BufferError': <class 
 'BufferError'>, 'Warning': <class 'Warning'>, 'UserWarning': 
 <class 'UserWarning'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <class 
 'DeprecationWarning'>, 'PendingDeprecationWarning': <class 
 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>, 'SyntaxWarning': <class 
 'SyntaxWarning'>, 'RuntimeWarning': <class 'RuntimeWarning'>, 
 'FutureWarning': <class 'FutureWarning'>, 'ImportWarning': <class 
 'ImportWarning'>, 'UnicodeWarning': <class 'UnicodeWarning'>, 
 'BytesWarning': <class 'BytesWarning'>, 'ResourceWarning': <class 
 'ResourceWarning'>, 'ConnectionError': <class 'ConnectionError'>, 
 'BlockingIOError': <class 'BlockingIOError'>, 'BrokenPipeError': 
 <class 'BrokenPipeError'>, 'ChildProcessError': <class 
 'ChildProcessError'>, 'ConnectionAbortedError': <class 
 'ConnectionAbortedError'>, 'ConnectionRefusedError': <class 
 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, 'ConnectionResetError': <class 
 'ConnectionResetError'>, 'FileExistsError': <class 
 'FileExistsError'>, 'FileNotFoundError': <class 
 'FileNotFoundError'>, 'IsADirectoryError': <class 
 'IsADirectoryError'>, 'NotADirectoryError': <class 
 'NotADirectoryError'>, 'InterruptedError': <class 
 'InterruptedError'>, 'PermissionError': <class 
 'PermissionError'>, 'ProcessLookupError': <class 
 'ProcessLookupError'>, 'TimeoutError': <class 'TimeoutError'>, 
 'open': <built-in function open>, 'quit': Use quit() or Ctrl-D 
 (i.e. EOF) to exit, 'exit': Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to 
 exit, 'copyright': Copyright (c) 2001-2021 Python Software 
 Foundation.
 All Rights Reserved.

 Copyright (c) 2000 BeOpen.com.
 All Rights Reserved.

 Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Corporation for National Research 
 Initiatives.
 All Rights Reserved.

 Copyright (c) 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, 
 Amsterdam.
 All Rights Reserved., 'credits':     Thanks to CWI, CNRI, 
 BeOpen.com, Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
 for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more 
 information., 'license': Type license() to see the full license 
 text, 'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) 
 for help about object.}}
```

I tried installing and uninstalling package m5. I also tried building gem5 from the beginning and running it again, but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was with the Python3 module m5. To fix the problem, I opened a Python3 console and wrote the following:

```
 >>> import m5
 >>> print(m5.__file__)
 /home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/m5/__init__.py
```

Then I went to the site-packages directory and deleted the m5 folder (or you can cut the folder to a personal directory in case you might need it later on). Then go to the gem5 directory (gem5 root folder) and run the script again.

```
 ~/gem5$ build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py
```